# Cannot achieve a WHERE clause on a float value

Tags: mysql, floating-point, where-clause

I have a 4.3 float value in a table.

When sending that request :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE floatfield = 4.3
```

is return an empty result.

Even when trying ;

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE floatfield = '4.3'
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188139/check-for-equality-on-a-mysql-float-field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Floating-point does not have infinite precision](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html), and `4.3` cannot be represented exactly in a finite number of binary digits.

Comment: Binary floating point (which nearly every computer system in the world uses) cannot represent 4.3 precisely in a finite number of bits.

Answer (score 2):

Use Column LIKE float instead of Column = float. Don't get the terminology behind this, it probably just matching up from the starting of the value or cut out the unseen precision digit and treat it like varchar.

Comment: Answer works in my case, but a technical explanation of exactly how it works would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `x_cast_to_float`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `x_cast_to_float`(number FLOAT) RETURNS FLOAT
    NO SQL
    BEGIN
        RETURN number;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE floatfield = x_cast_to_float(4.3)<br />
```