# How to search a value from DB with float value in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I am developing one API which is responsible for searching with float values like `99.99 or 67.00.....`,Below query should get the data if we enter `9999` inorder to `99.99`,but i need to show results if the user search with the `99.99` only..

```
$searchBooks=Books::where("price",$price)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

testing for exact float values is a bad idea since floating point precision is not enough for equality.

```
$searchBooks=Books::whereRaw("abs(price-{$price})<0.0001")->get();
```

see more details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188139/10573560).